# jquery code explanation

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I need an explanation on what it does:

```
function delaymethod(settings) {
    settings.timeout = settings.timeout || 2000; 
    var start = new Date();

    var id = parent.setInterval(function () {
        if (settings.condition()) {
            parent.clearInterval(id);
            if (settings.success) {
                settings.success();
            }
        }

        var now = new Date();
        if (now - start > settings.timeout) {
            parent.clearInterval(id);

            if (settings.fail) {
                settings.fail();
            } else if (settings.success) {
                settings.success();
            }
        }

    }, 200);

}
```

Comment: Where's jQuery? If you make the question more specific, it will be easier to help

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble understanding? There are a few things going on here.

Comment: None of this is jQuery and as Andrew said, there are quite a few things going on here. Can you clarify?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: specifying the context in which you would sue or find this will help understanding and explaining the code..

Comment: It is doing what the method name says: It is `delay`ing a `method` (`settings.success`).

Comment: @Felix: Not really doing what the method name implies.  A method called `delay`, would take a function and call it with a delay. The method is poorly named.

Comment: @muirbot.. This does sound like a homework assignment. An Apple to the person who gets this guy an A+ on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sets a periodic timer (`parent.setInterval`) that fires every 200 ms. Whenever the timer fires:

1. It checks `settings.condition()` and if it is fulfilled, it stops the timer and calls a `success()` function.
2. It checks if a timeout has occurred since the timer was originally set (`now - start > settings.timeout`) and if so, it stops the timer and calls either `fail()` or `success()`, whichever is defined.

Comment: It is what the code is doing, but I hate promoting questions that aren't well formulated. Questions at SO are supposed to be useful to others. I'd rather encourage the OP to think about the problem, teach them to fish, don't just hand them the answer. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @Juan Mendes: I fully agree with you but I'm myself unsure about where to draw the line for useful questions. In this specific case, I just decided to answer the question as it was asked.